# How to combine 3.4ghz intel processor with arduino board

Tags: power, shields

Im totally new to arduino but have some programming experience. I have an idea that i would like to realize but it requires way better hardware than what a standard arduino board offers. I would like to use my 3.4 ghz intel processor for example...

The question might seem very stupid to most people here but i actually did not find the answer anywhere (here, google, arduino website), but is it possible to combine the simplicity of arduino and the power of pc-level hardware without using a server? (The calculations should be made locally on the arduino).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How real time do you need things to be?

Arduino gives you very good control of timings because there is no operating system getting in the way switching between tasks in the background.

If you need hard real time then you need to work bare metal, mbed gives you a more processing power while still maintaining the ease of use and reliable tight timing. That will get you up to around 150 MHz with an FPU but still a long way from PC capabilities.

You can run bare metal code on any CPU but doing so without an easy to use set of libraries can have a very steep learning curve, I don't know of any faster systems that allow you to do this in an accessible way.

If you can live with a few ms of delay in the system then you can run something with an OS which opens up a lot more possibilities. The Pi is at the low end of the range in both price and performance. The odroid or beagleboard boards give you more power for more money but are still fairly good in terms of price. I'm not sure what exactly you want to do but four 2 GHz CPUs is enough to do quite a lot of number crunching if you can multi-thread the task.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do.

An Arduino gives you are simple low cost board for interfacing to peripherals.  If you are interfacing to kit then you probably want to stick with a microprocessor because of its real time behaviour, its low cost and its simplicity.

If you then want to crunch numbers send the data back to a beast of a processor and crunch numbers, where you have features like floating point and clever stuff.

The two processors you talk about are both good at what they are aimed at, but not much use at the other.,

Looking at it another way, you are a farmer and have a tractor for ploughing the fields, a quad bike for chasing sheep, and a Porsche for nipping down the shops.  You could go shopping in the tractor same as you could try to plough the field with the Porsche, but you look a bit of a [fool].

You could look at Netduinos, ESP8226, ESP32, Pi's or PICs.

You can get a PC card that talks to an I2C bus and could control the microprocessors using that.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can combine it, but it depends what you need. If you say you need to do the calculations on the Arduino, and assuming the electronics will also be driven from the Arduino, I wonder what you want your 3.4 intel processor to do.

If you want to let the Arduino use the intel directly, that will be impossible or at least impractical. The number of pins used by the intel will be very high and the Arduino runs on 16 MHz so never can provide the intel with enough data to keep it busy.

Comment: Okay thanks, do you know if there any alternatives to arduino that would support heavier calculations then? Something like a pc-level motherboard but similar to arduino (so that you can easily combine different electronics, parts etc)

Comment: Within Arduino there is the Due which is like an arm processor and has more processor power but not close to a 3.4 intel either ... you could either go into the direction of raspberry pi, or maybe you should rethink your project. Like asking the question why you need a 3.4 GHz intel, why not do the calculations on a 'normal'  computer?

Comment: I am going to write a program that recognizes objects in a video in real time (probably at around 15 fps). Since it would be in real time the response should be as fast as possible, that is why id like to skip the streaming of data part. The goal is to make a robot that is independant of other devices so i cant have an usb connection either.

Comment: hmm actually, raspberry pi 3 has 1.2ghz that would probably suffice to be honest.

Comment: For video the Arduino will be too slow anyway. You need a lot of bandwidth for processing video. Probably the raspberry pi 3 is the way to go ... you could do the video processing on that, and leave the motor controls probably to the Arduino (if you need it when you have the raspberry).

Comment: Though the Raspberry Pi models are pretty anemic compared to regular PCs, they also do have a surprisingly decent GPU on them that may come in useful in applications such as image processing. And of course they have all the nice IO pins etc. like the Arduino. If you need PC-level power, you probably want to build your robot around a laptop.